# I am getting "POST http://localhost:5000/api/users 400 (Bad Request)" response while using axios.post from action in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, axios, mern

I am using axios.post in my auth action by which I want to post my register detail that I am getting from register component . But I am getting bad request response and with error

```
"Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:66)"
```

Please find the below code for my Auth  action ,Register  component  and server code for registering users please let me know the mistake that I making here :

//auth action :

```
import axios from "axios";
import {setAlert} from './alerts';
import {REGISTER_FAIL,REGISTER_SUCCESS} from './types';



// Register User  
export const register =  ({name,email,password}) => async (dispatch) =>  {

    
    
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  
  }
  

    const body=JSON.stringify({name,email,password});
    
   console.log(body);
 
    try {
      const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/users', body, {
      headers: headers
    })
      dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data
      });
      
    } catch (err) {
      const errors = err.response.data.errors;
  /*
     if (errors) {
       errors.forEach((error) => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')));
      }
      */
     console.log(err);
  
      dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_FAIL
      });
    }
   
    



  };
  // , "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

//  Register component

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setAlert } from '../../actions/alerts';
import { register} from '../../actions/auth';//importing register action
import './../../App.css';
export const Register = (props) => {

    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
      name:'',
      email:'',
      password:'',
      password2:''
     })

    const {name,email,password,password2}={...formData};

    const onChange=(e)=>setFormData({...formData,[e.target.name]:e.target.value});

    const onSubmit=(e)=>{
     e.preventDefault();
     if(password!==password2){
         props.setAlert('password do not match','danger');
     }
     else{
       
         props.register({name,email,password});
     }
    }

    return (
        <div >
            <h1 className="large text-primary">Sign Up</h1>
      <p className="lead"><i className="fas fa-user"></i> Create Your Account</p>
      <form className="form" onSubmit={e=>onSubmit(e)}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Name"
           name="name" value={name}
            onChange={e=>onChange(e)} 
            required />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input type="email"
           placeholder="Email Address" 
           name="email" value={email}
            onChange={e=>onChange(e)} />
          <small className="form-text"
            >This site uses Gravatar so if you want a profile image, use a
            Gravatar email</small
          >
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            name="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={e=>onChange(e)}
            minLength="6"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Confirm Password"
            name="password2"
            value={password2}
            onChange={e=>onChange(e)}
            minLength="6"
          />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" value="Register" />
      </form>
      <p className="my-1">
        Already have an account? <Link to="/login">Sign In</Link>
      </p>
        </div>
    )
}


export  default  connect(null,{setAlert,register}) (Register);
```

Server API code :

```
const express =require('express');
const User=require('../../models/User');
const gravatar=require('gravatar');

const {check, validationResult}=require('express-validator');

const bcrypt=require('bcryptjs');
const jwt=require('jsonwebtoken');
const router=express.Router();
const config=require('config');

// signin

router.post('/',[
check('name','name is required').not().isEmpty(),
check('email','Need valid email').isEmail(),
check('password','length should be greater than 6').isLength({min:6})

],async(req,res)=>{
    const errors=validationResult(req);
    if(!errors.isEmpty()){
        return res.status(400).json({errors:errors.array()});
    }

    const {name,email,password}=req.body;
    
    try{
        let user= await User.findOne({email});
        

    if(user){
      return  res.status(400).json({errors:'user already exist !'})

    }
    const avatar =gravatar.url({email})

     user= new User({
        name,
        email,
        password,
        avatar
    })

    const salt=await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    
     user.password=await bcrypt.hash(password,salt);

     await user.save();
  
     const payload={
         user:{
            id:user.id
         }
        
     }

    jwt.sign(payload,config.get('jwtsecret'),(err,token)=>{
        if(err){
             throw err;
        }
       res.json({token});
      
    })


    }
    

    catch(err){
        
     return res.status(400).json({errors:errors.message})
    }

    
    
});



module.exports=router;
```

Comment: This looks reasonable but the missing piece is knowing what API you're actually talking to and whether it accepts JSON-encoded input or not. You're talking to localhost:5000 so that's presumably a node app that you wrote, but we can't see that code.

Comment: Now I have added my API code above as well

Comment: Your API code sends 400 errors in at least two situations according to your source code. Duplicate users and a more general-purpose try/catch block. Details are sent with the error, so look in the network panel to check which message is being received. Also add console.log statements inside the API handler to see what it is doing.